# Why no data insert into database by register form without showing error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I made a binary mlm register form and insert data into database but no data insert into database and no error show
here is controller

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Models\MemberExtra;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
  
    public function index(){
        return view('users.register');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'referrer_id' => 'required',
            'position' => 'required', 
            'username' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {  
         $ref_id = $data['referrer_id'];
        $poss = $data['position'];
        $posid =  getLastChildOfLR($ref_id,$poss);
 
        return User::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'referrer_id' => $data['referrer_id'],
            'position' => $data['position'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'join_date' => Carbon::today(),
            'posid' => $posid       
        ]);
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        $this->guard()->login($user);
        MemberExtra::create([
           'user_id' => $user['id'],
           'left_paid' => 0,
           'right_paid' => 0,
           'left_free' => 0,
           'right_free' => 0,
           'left_bv' => 0,
           'right_bv' => 0,
        ]);
       updateMemberBelow($user['id'], 'FREE');  
       return $this->registered($request, $user) ?: redirect()->route('home');
      
    }
}
```

HERE is blade form

```
  <!-- Extends template page -->
@extends('layout.app')

<!-- Specify content -->
@section('content')

<h3>Add Users</h3>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

      
          <!-- Alert message (start) -->
        @if(Session::has('message'))
        <div class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class') }}">
          <span style="color:green">{{ Session::get('message') }}</span>
        </div>
        @endif
       
             <form action="{{route('user.store')}}" method="post" id="subjectForm">
                {{csrf_field()}}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Referrer Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" value="{{old('ref_name')}}" id="ref_name" placeholder="Ref Name" class="form-control" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div id="ref">

                    </div>
                   @if ($errors->has('referrer_id'))
                   <span class="help-block">
                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('referrer_id') }}</strong>
                   </span>
                   @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                
                <label for="Select Position" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Position</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select class="select_panel" id="position" name="position" required>
                                <option disabled selected>Select Position</option>
                                <option value="L">Left</option>
                                <option value="R">Right</option>
                            </select>
                            <div id="ref_pos">

                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('position'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('position') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">userName* </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="username" id="username" value="{{old('username')}}" placeholder="username" class="form-control" name= "username">
                        @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email* </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="email" value="{{old('email')}}" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name= "email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password*</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <span class="help-block">*Required fields</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
            </form> <!-- /form -->
        </div> <!-- ./container -->
@endsection
@section('script')
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('keyup','#ref_name',function() {
                var ref_id = $('#ref_name').val();
                var token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
                var postion = $('#position').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"{{route('get.ref.id')}}",
                    data:{
                        'ref_id': ref_id ,
                        '_token' : token
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#ref").html(data);
                        if(postion ==null || postion =='L' || postion=='R'){
                            updateHand()
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).on('change', '#position', function () {
                    updateHand();
            });
            function updateHand() {
                var pos = $('#position').val();
                var referrer_id = $('#referrer_id').val();
                var token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"{{route('get.user.position')}}",
                    data:{
                        'pos': pos ,
                        'referrer_id': referrer_id ,
                        '_token' : token
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#ref_pos").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

here is register form before click register buttom
[image]

here is after click

[image]

here is route

```
 
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');

//register
Route::get('/register',[RegisterController::class,'index'])->name('user.register');
Route::post('/user/store',[RegisterController::class,'register'])->name('user.store');
Route::post('/get/ref/id', [FontendController::class,'getRefId'])->name('get.ref.id');
Route::post('/get/position', [FontendController::class,'getPosition'])->name('get.user.position');
```

I find the cause of this
but not see, I not understand why no show error and why data not insert
can someone help me
Please

Comment: Are you sure you sent all required inputs? Can you try `dd($data)` after removing the validator on the controller side?

Comment: have you added your new columns in fillable property in user model?

Comment: Several of your inputs are missing `name` attributes(referrer, password), so will not be sent along with the form. Your validator is probably failing because of this.

Answer (score 1):

[aynber commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69737926/why-no-data-insert-into-database-by-register-form-without-showing-error-in-larav/69738530#comment123268900_69737926):

> Several of your inputs are missing `name` attributes(referrer, password), so will not be sent along with the form. Your validator is probably failing because of this.

This was precisely the issue: the attribute was missing. As soon as I filled it in, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

it think the referrer_id filed not available in your blade form so its give an validation error,because in validation you give the name as referrer_id and passing the referrer_name from your form.